# How to make call form iOS swift with IVR call (i.e. #123#) from swift app on button click

Tags: swift

I am trying to implement call on `#123#` in swift when user click on button. I am writing below code to make a call but it's not working.

```
  let iVRPhoneNumber = "#123#"
  guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(iVRPhoneNumber)") else { return }
//It's alwasy returning from here. If I removed # from iVRPhoneNumber string then it's working.
  if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(iVRPhoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
        application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding percentage encoding to the phone number string should work,

```
let iVRPhoneNumber = "#123#"
    guard let phoneNumber = iVRPhoneNumber.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return }
    guard let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") else { return }
    print(phoneCallURL)
          let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
      }
```